# R Trend of days over several years

Tags: r, date, lm, lubridate, trend

I want to calculate different kind of trends with this testframe.

```
date_list = seq(ymd('2000-01-15'),ymd('2010-09-18'),by='day')
testframe = data.frame(Date = date_list)
testframe$Day = substr(testframe$Date, start = 6, stop = 10)
testframe$V1 = runif(3900, 2.0, 35.0)
testframe$V2 = runif(3900, 5.0, 40.0)
testframe$V3 = runif(3900, -10.0, 10.0)
testframe$V4 = seq(from = 5, to = 45, length.out = 3900)
```

I have a Date column which contains the exact date. The days column contains the extracted days and months and then I have 4 columns with different values.

I want to do two different things:

1. Calculate the trend of the values of each day over the years. So In the end I only have a column which each single day (no years) and then the slope of the values V1-V4 for each day. The slope should be calculated for each day from the year 2000 to 2010.
2. The same as above but this time I want to calculate the slope not only from each single day, I also want to take the mean of the values 15 days before and 15 days after each Day. So for the slope of the values of e.g. 2000-02-01, I want to have the mean of all values from 2000-01-17 to 2000-02-16. After I have the mean of these days, I want to do the same as above.

My only effort so far was to create the "Day" column to use it for the `aggregate` command...but it didnt bring me anywhere so far.

UPDATE: I found a nice package named `TTR` which contains a moving average function. That is what I need. I only didnt find out how to use it for several columns:

```
library(TTR)
mavg.15day = SMA(testframe$V1, n=15)
```

Unfortunately it does only use the 15 days before each date.

Comment: so `testframe[paste0("new_col",1:4)] <- lapply(testframe[3:6], SMA, n = 15)` ?

Comment: Thanks! yes that would be great to calculate the moving average. But my main problem is now how to calculate a trend of each day over all the year. So I want to have all means of the 1st of February for example (would be 11 values in this case) and then calculate the trend of these 11 values.

Comment: Ok I checked it now, the SMA function is not really want I wanted. It only calculates the 15 days before my desired Date, but not also 15 days after it.